# Warning: Value assigned to primitive will be lost for craco config

Tags: webpack, create-react-app, craco

The following `craco` config has been taken as is from multiple articles on the internet that show how to include your monorepo UI library into the CRA build flow:

```
const path = require('path');
const { getLoader, loaderByName } = require('@craco/craco');

const uiPath = path.join(__dirname, '../../packages/ui');

module.exports = {
    webpack: {
        alias: {},
        plugins: [],
        configure: (webpackConfig, { env, paths }) => {
            const { isFound, match } = getLoader(webpackConfig, loaderByName('babel-loader'));
            if (isFound) {
                const include = Array.isArray(match.loader.include) ? match.loader.include : [match.loader.include];
                match.loader.include = include.concat([uiPath]);
            }
            return webpackConfig;
        },
    },
};
```

...which works very well, but I don't understand why my IDE keeps showing the warning `Value assigned to primitive will be lost` for the following line:

`match.loader.include = include.concat([uiPath]);`